# How to make a div overlay that exactly matches image size

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am creating a website and would like a user to be able to hover their mouse over an image and get more information about the image. I have this working correctly but I cannot figure out how to darken the other images that are not selected. Ideally I would like to create an overlay div using html and css that exactly matches the dimensions of a responsive image. When not hovered over this overlay div would use a transparent color to darken the image a bit. How can I make this div responsive to the image?

Here is my codepen to see what I am talking about
https://codepen.io/klaurtar/pen/NJgrOR

```
.overlay {
    width: 55%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

    z-index: 10;

    &--p1 {
        left: 0;
        top: -2rem;
        height: 20rem;
    }

    &--p2 {
        right: 0;
        top: 2rem;
        height: 20rem;
    }

    &--p3 {
        left: 20%;
        top: 10rem;
        height: 22rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/320/240" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```